# Using command defined in a main file in subfiles

Tags: subfiles

I am using the package `subfiles` with the main document as `main.tex` and inside the `main.tex` there are:

```
\subfile{file1.tex}
\subfile{file2.tex}
```

and I defined some commands inside `main.tex`

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\todoiteminline}[3]{
    \todoitemtemplate{#1}{#2}{#3}{inline}{red}
}
```

but when I compile the whole project, these commands are not recognized in subfile. The error is `undefined control sequence` where I used the command `todoiteminline`.

How can I use this command in each subfile?

Comment: What is the structure of your subfiles?

Comment: However, if you don't need to compile every document as a standalone file, you can also try to use `\input{file.tex}` or `include{file.tex}`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling `main`?

Answer (score 2):

Defining the command in the main file is fine, it will also work in the subfiles. Take for example

```
\newcommand{\todoiteminline}[3]{
    \textcolor{red}{#1}
    \textcolor{blue}{#3}
    \textcolor{green}{#3}
}
```

However the command `\todoitemtemplate`, which you are trying to use inside the `\newcommand` does not exist, thus your custom command `\todoiteminline` will cause an `undefined control sequence` error, as it tries to use `\todoitemtemplate`.

With a suitable definition of `\todoitemtemplate` your definition should work fine, in the main file as well as in the subfiles.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling only a subfile, the command is only known if it was created in the *preamble* of the main file.

Working main.tex excerpt:

```
\newcommand{\todoiteminline}[3]{
    \textcolor{red}{#1}
    \textcolor{blue}{#3}
    \textcolor{green}{#3}
}
\begin{document}
```

Failing main.tex excerpt:

```
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\todoiteminline}[3]{
    \textcolor{red}{#1}
    \textcolor{blue}{#3}
    \textcolor{green}{#3}
}
```

If the main file compiles, and the subfile on its own does not, this can be the reason.

---

If the main file does not compile because of this command, [consider samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353681/102826) that your defined command `\todoiteminline` was never defined. Then, the problem has nothing to do with the subfiles package.